# Preference Activity is crashing on Android 2.3

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-preferences

*Note to moderators- I understand this topic was highly discussed in the past. However, the more I dig deep in, the more lost I was. And I believe mine is a one off issue which I could not find anywhere in the community. If you have already come across a similar post, I recommend you sharing before closing this question.*

Hi,

I am into using one PreferenceActivity class for all android versions. I followed [This link](http://www.blackmoonit.com/2012/07/all_api_prefsactivity/)

The activity class is

```
public class PreferencesActivity extends PreferenceActivity implements OnPreferenceChangeListener {
protected Method mLoadHeaders;
protected Method mHasHeaders;

public boolean isNewV11Prefs() {
    if(null != mHasHeaders && null != mLoadHeaders) {
        try {
            return (Boolean)mHasHeaders.invoke(this);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return false;
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    try {
        mLoadHeaders = getClass().getMethod("loadHeadersFromResource", int.class, List.class);
        mHasHeaders = getClass().getMethod("hasHeaders");
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if(!isNewV11Prefs()) {
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preference_account_settings);

        PreferenceManager preferenceManager = getPreferenceManager();  
    }
}

@Override
public void onBuildHeaders(List<Header> aTarget) {
    try {
        mLoadHeaders.invoke(this, new Object[]{R.xml.preference_headers, aTarget});
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}



@Override
public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
    Log.i(TAG_NAME, "preference change..!");

    return true;
}

/**
 * Helper method to forcibly set context to a preference.
 * This is a bug reported for Android TabHost. As a workaround, 
 * a known context is explicitly set to preference.
 * @param context parent context
 * @param p preference instance
 */
private void forceContext(Context context, Preference p){
    try {
        Field field = Preference.class.getDeclaredField("mContext");
        field.setAccessible(true);
        field.set(p, getParent());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }  
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
static public class PrefsFragment extends PreferenceFragment implements OnPreferenceChangeListener {
    private CheckBoxPreference searchAllAccounts;
    private ListPreference accountType;
    private ListPreference searchFor;
    private String accountTypeDesc;
    private String searchForDesc;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Context context = getActivity().getApplicationContext();
        int prefResourceId = context.getResources().getIdentifier(getArguments().getString("pref-resource"), "xml", context.getPackageName());

        addPreferencesFromResource(prefResourceId);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
        return true;
    }


}
}
```

The preference screen opens up on all android versions > 2.3
However, when I do it on 2.3 emulator, the app throws the following error.

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: loadHeadersFromResource
at java.lang.ClassCache.findMethodByName(ClassCache.java:247)
at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:962)
at com.android.mobile.screens.PreferencesFragment.onCreate(PreferencesFragment.java:62)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

What am I lacking? Any clue?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, set you built platform to something > API 11, then you won't need to use reflection. But in this case you need to check the api probramatically, i.e.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        ActionBar bar = this.getActionBar();
        bar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        bar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);

        loadHeadersFromResource(R.xml.settings_headers, headersList);
    }

    else {

        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings);
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh, silly me! I forgot to move that bit and spent hours debugging. However, the actual culprit was something else. I was forcefully setting a wrong context which threw exceptions. All sorted now :-)

Answer (score 0):

`PreferenceActivity.loadHeadersFromResource` is available since api `11`, you can not use it if your device has a lower api level. [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceActivity.html#loadHeadersFromResource%28int,%20java.util.List%3Candroid.preference.PreferenceActivity.Header%3E%29) you can find the documentation